# How can I limit/stop the number of characters fgets reads?

Tags: c

I need to my code to only read words of 10 characters and no longer. The purpose of the code is to detect anagrams. How can I limit fgets to only read 10 characters and after that display a message printf("Word is longer than 10 characters please try again"). My code is below I'd appreciate any help.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    
    // Sorting function to sort words
    
    void lowercase(char *str);
    void removespaces(char *str);
    int lol(char a[], char b[], int *_lenword1, int *_lenword2);
    
    int main(void){ 
    
    //Initiating two strings with a maximum limit fo 10 characters
     char FirstWord[12];
     char SecondWord[12];
    
    /* Console requests input of the first word, fgets reads word of unknown legnth without reading more than buffer allows
       Index begins at 0 to use strlen excess allocated characters can be replaced with /0                                      */
        printf("Please enter the first word: \n");
        fgets(FirstWord, 12,stdin);
        FirstWord[strlen(FirstWord)-1]='\0';
      
        printf("Please enter the second word: \n");
        fgets(SecondWord, 12, stdin);
        SecondWord[strlen(SecondWord)-1]='\0';
    
        int lenword1 = strlen(FirstWord); 
        int lenword2 = strlen(SecondWord);
        
     //Relaying strings to functions to convert all characters to lowercase   
       lowercase(FirstWord);
       lowercase(SecondWord);
    // Relaying strings to removespaces function so spaces in string are removed
       removespaces(FirstWord);
       removespaces(SecondWord);
    //Decisions 
       if (lol(FirstWord, SecondWord, &lenword1, &lenword2))
        printf("%s and %s are anagrams.\n",FirstWord, SecondWord);
      else
        printf("%s and %s are not anagrams.\n", FirstWord, SecondWord);
    
      return 0;
    }
    
    //Function to sort characters
    int lol(char a[], char b[], int *_lenword1, int *_lenword2){
    if (*_lenword1 == *_lenword2){
    int first[26] = {0}, second[26] = {0}, c=0;
    
      // Calculating frequency of characters of the first string
    
      while (a[c] != '\0') {
        first[a[c]-'a']++;
        c++;
      }
    
      c = 0;
    
      while (b[c] != '\0') {
        second[b[c]-'a']++;
        c++;
      }
    
      // Comparing the frequency of characters
    
      for (c = 0; c < 26; c++){
        if (first[c] != second[c]){
          return 0;
        }
      }
      return 1;
    }
    else{ // if different lengths - then they're not anagrams
            return 0; 
        }
    }
    // Function to convert all letters to lower case (to allow for case sensitivy anagram detection)
    void lowercase(char* str){
    for (uint8_t i=0; str[i]; i++ ){
       str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
    }
    }
    // Function to remove all spaces from a given string 
    void removespaces( char* str) 
    { 
       const char* d = str;
        do {
            while (*d == ' ') {
                ++d;
            }
        } while (*str++ == *d++);
    }
```

Comment: It's usually easiest to read words of arbitrary length, then call `strlen`, then complain if it's too long.

Comment: Rather than limit input to 10, allow generous, like 100, input and _detect_ overlong input .  User input is  evil.

Comment: `FirstWord[strlen(FirstWord)-1]='\0';` is bad. What happens if `fgets` *fail*? Use `FirstWord[strcspn(FirstWord, "\n")] = '\0';` instead, *after* making sure that `fgets` didn't fail.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `FirstWord[strlen(FirstWord)-1]` also a hacker exploit when `fgets()` _reads_ an initial null character.

Comment: As for your problem, how about something like `int res = scanf("%10s%c", FirstName, &temp); if (res == EOF || res == 2 && !isspace(temp)) { /* Error, or input too long */}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char v[12];
    
    //Loop checks if fgets succeeded and if there is '\n' in the string:
    while (!fgets(v, 12, stdin) || strcspn(v, "\n") == 11){
        if(feof(stdin)) {
             printf("Error: End of file reached.\n");
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("Error: The word is longer than 10 characters, try again.\n");
        for(int ch=getchar(); ch != '\n' && ch != EOF; ch=getchar());
    }
    v[strcspn(v, "\n")] = '\0';
    
    printf("%s\n", v);

    return 0;
}
```

If there isn't a '\n' in the string then the word has more than 10 characters.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica If `fgets` returns `NULL` the loop continues.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've changed it.

Comment: Lots of good improvements. UV.  For deeper review and to get rid of other corner weaknesses, consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Here it is:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256166/limit-fgets-input-to-up-to-a-certain-number-of-characters